# 5.0 update not received

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Hi guys I searched alot but not found any thing related to this. So if anyone tell me what's the reason for this.

I just purchased Google nexus 5 and upgraded from 4.4.2 to 4.4.4 and now waiting for 5.0 update on my device. But It has been over a month that I didn't received any updates and where others guys have received 5.0.1 as well. So anyone having same issue or something wrong with my device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, that's weird Lollipop for Nexus5 device have already been rolled out all over, I wonder why you haven't got your hands over the Lollipop? Did you tried checking your device check for updates button under the settings ?? If you still didn't get the update then maybe you should wait a little more while for the update to show up or if you don't want to wait then can always flash the factory image downloaded and flashed over the device manually!

Comment: Yes Peter.  I tried hitting check update button several times. But always a message your system is upto date. And flash is an option but just wanted to know why this is happening.  Is there any way to ask Google or report for same?

Comment: No @Karnal vaid, I think still OTA update haven't been rolled out over your region I would say either wait a little more while and if you don't want to then head over to the https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images and get the stock factory image for Android Lollipop downloaded and flash it over to your nexus5.

Comment: Well friends in my circle already got the update and we live in same region as well. But their purchased nexus 5 almost 10 months earlier . And flashing phone will also flash my phone guarantee agreement :-) ... So was finding a way to reach  Google for this.

Comment: No, @Kamal Vaid flashing the device with factory image isn't going to void your warranty. And one more thing that's weird your friends have got the Android Lollipop update but you don't have ??? maybe you should try visiting over to the nearest support seeking answers or you always have the option for flash factory image over your device. One more thing do make a backup of your data if you decide to go forward in flashing factory image !

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Seems flash factory image way to go right now.  But will wait for one more week before opting the solution you suggested.

Comment: You could use the [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) to flash lollipop, and then check all the config to make sure it's fully back to stock - so not voided warranty and then when the time comes in the future you will still receive OTA updates. Easiest way for a Nexus device.

Comment: @kamalvaid No worries at all that totally depends upon you! I wish you should receive Android Lollipop update by the end of this week :) maybe you should keep your fingers crossed!

Comment: Thanks Novocaine.  So I followed your link. I ve to hit to back to stock button in this one?

Comment: @peter ya I just hope your wish come true otherwise I've to forcefully to that :-D

Answer (score 0):

You could just wait it out, as you will eventually be prompted, or you have a couple of options.

You could try and speed up the update by trying to trigger it again, try wiping google play services data (it worked on my nexus 4).

Or you could flash the system image

A better option however would be to just flash the ota file, which can be done without unlocking your bootloader.

Get the ota, and follow the instructions at this link:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/12/23/flash-all-the-things-lollipop-ota-update-zip-file-roundup/